# Hide and show particular form items on checked and unchecked selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using the below given code to hide and show particular form items, but this doesn't work kindly let me know what I am missing in my code?

HTML:

```
<input id="id_code_col" type="checkbox" name="code_col"></input>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var selectBox = jQuery('#id_code_col');
selectBox.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
      $('#id_FullColumn').show();
      $('#id_FirstColumn').hide();
      $('#id_SecondColumn').hide();

    }
    else {
      $('#id_FullColumn').hide();
      $('#id_FirstColumn').show();
      $('#id_SecondColumn').show();
    }
});
});
```

N.B: I can not add or remove anything from html. What ever I have to do is to do it with script. Kindly help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this:

```
if(this.checked)
{
// checked
}

else
{
// unchecked
}
```

for your case:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var selectBox = jQuery('#id_code_col');
    selectBox.change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          $('#id_FullColumn').show();
          $('#id_FirstColumn').hide();
          $('#id_SecondColumn').hide();

        }
        else {
          $('#id_FullColumn').hide();
          $('#id_FirstColumn').show();
          $('#id_SecondColumn').show();
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** along with **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** selector to check whether your checkbox is checked or not, so try to use:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

or pure javascript using:

```
if(this.checked)
```

instead of:

```
if ($(this).val() == '1') {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
selectBox.change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#id_FullColumn').show();
      $('#id_FirstColumn').hide();
      $('#id_SecondColumn').hide();

    }
    else {
      $('#id_FullColumn').hide();
      $('#id_FirstColumn').show();
      $('#id_SecondColumn').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
 if ($(this).val() == '1') {
```

to this

```
 if (this.checked) {
```

---

Because you don't have to check for the value to 1, as your checkbox doesn't have any value set to 1.

So you have to check for the state of that  checkbox with `checked` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var selectBox = jQuery('#id_code_col');
            selectBox.change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    alert("checked");
                }
                else {
                    alert("unchecked");
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          $(function(){
                $('#id_code_col').change(function(){
                  if($(this.checked)){
                   alert('checked');
                    }else{
                     alert('unchecked');
                  }
                 });
           });
```